# How can I enable my custom domain support email forward to Gmail or Outlook?

Tags: email, configuration, dns

We have a domain name(for instance `example.com`, **register at GoDaddy** ), and now we'd like to use our own custom email address (for instance `contact@example.com`), but we are not intend to manage the Email server related stuff, we just want to forward the inbox mail to *Gmail* or *Outlook* .etc account.

So someone write a email to `contact@example`, then we can check it within *Gmail* or *Outlook*.

How to configure all above stuff? Any complete tutorial can offer help?

Comment: what is your panel? WebSitePanel/CPanle/Helm?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about configuring email

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With whom did you register your domain name? The ease/difficulty depends on this. The steps that follow assume your DNS registrar offers email forwarding. If they do not, the steps would be too involved to discuss here.

**Incoming mail**:

- *STEP 1. Arrange for your DNS registrar to forward your emails to Gmail*

Even if you want Gmail to handle this domain's mail, the emails *still* need one of your DNS registrar's mail servers to reroute them. All this mail server will be doing is rerouting *gerald@example.com* to *jerry@gmail.com*, but without it, you'd be blindly sending emails to *gerald@example.com* to Google, and Google would not know to which of its users the mail is intended.

The short story is: log on to your DNS registrar's website and look for an *"email"* or *"email forwarding"* section where you can specify that you want forwarding enabled, and to which Gmail address(es).

- *STEP 2. Change the DNS registrar's MX Record to point to your DNS registrar's mail server*

You might then also need to set the *"MX record"* for *"example.com"* to point to your DNS registrar's mail servers. It is likely your registrar will set this up for you, or at least provide instructions, when you configure your email. See, people who send you email will send it first to your DNS registrar, who will forward the emails to Google.

- *GoDaddy.com Help pages re: setting up Incoming mail Forwarding*:

I gather you registered your domain with [godaddy.com](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1725/setting-up-a-forwarding-account-in-the-email-control-center) - they have a tutorial on how to set up mail-forwarding on [this webpage](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1725/setting-up-a-forwarding-account-in-the-email-control-center). The tutorial seems fairly good. I do notice one confusing step: you should literally use *'smtp.secureserver.net'* as the *mx record*, they make it seem like it's just an example. *'smtp.secureserver.net'* is actually GoDaddy's server, and the article doesn't make that very clear.

If you want to see a walk-through, some fellow even made a [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rTIs2kAs5c) last year.

**Outgoing mail**:

- *STEP 3. (Optional) Log in to Gmail and change your reply-to address*

You hardly need to worry about outgoing mail. This is because the email protocols let you choose any old *"reply-to"* address you wish. In other words, I can send you an email from *"sjobs@apple.com"* or any other email address, and all normal email clients will show that as the sender's address when they receive emails from me.

So, once you have your incoming mail set up, you may wish to tell your Gmail account that your outgoing emails should appear to be sent from *'gerald@example.com'*. You can do so by visiting this section of your Gmail account settings:

*"Settings" > "Accounts" > "Send mail as:"*

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, we register at GoDaddy.